# menu design and event wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent, menuitem

[image]I have a WPF application that contains a menu like in the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

```
<MenuItem Header="_Paramètres"
          Height="60"
          Width="188"
          FontWeight="Bold"
          FontSize="16"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
          MouseMove="MenuItem_MouseMove_1"
          Name="param">
  <MenuItem.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                         StartPoint="0.5,0">
      <GradientStop Color="Black"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="White"
                    Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </MenuItem.Background>
  <MenuItem Header="_Régler"
            Height="30"
            Width="188"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            FontSize="16"
            Click="regler_Click_1"
            x:Name="regler"
            Background="#FF150202"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
</MenuItem>
```

My problem is when the mouse focus in the menu `param` the control became blue to indicate that the focus is their. I'd like to avoid this and to add the light in the text when the mouse is on the menu (like in google.com 's menu)

How can i do it? what changes i have to do in the code?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the current highlighting behavior, please? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the  ItemContainerStyle for the Menu control, in this way you will be able to change the IsSelected state look and feel. An easier way for to do this is making a copy  of the ItemContainerStyle and then modify it. (If you are on Blend or VS2012, right click on container menu, edit additional templates, ItemContainerStyle, make a copy). Hope this helps, I think it's will...